# Selecting missing values from a comparison of 3 tables (or more)

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have 3 tables with the same columns, originating from different sources. Primarily, I have Column A and Column B, which should have unique combinations.
I want to compare Column A and Column B between the three tables, and in case there are missing values, select the pair of A and B values and the table they are missing from. Preferably a count of the missing values as well.

*The end result, should be a listagg containing values of Column A paired with the count of missing Column B values, and from which table the values are missing from*

Example, with specific column names:

Column A = **Region**, Column B = **Customer_ID**

Then we have 3 tables:

```
Table 1 : Table1.Region | Table1.Customer_ID
Table 2 : Table2.Region | Table2.Customer_ID
Table 3 : Table3.Region | Table3.Customer_ID
```

In the case above, Table 1 is missing 6 values that is present in Table 2 and Table 3, for Region "001".

Also, Table 2 is missing 2 values for Region "002".

The wanted result should yield a `Listagg`, like so:

```
result: ("Table 1", 001, 6; "Table 2", 002, 2;)
```

Comment: I don't see anything "missing". You said that Table 1 is missing 6 values. Is it? Maybe for you, but not for me. What "region 001"? Where is it? Sample data would probably help.

Comment: Consider "001" as a region_id. The example was to show the wanted result after the 3 tables go through the comparison logic - which discovers that Table1 is missing 6 rows that were present in Table 2 and Table 3, while Table 2 was missing 2 rows that otherwise existed in Table 1 and Table 3. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* would really be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I make a union all of the three tables with tag colum "tab"
- Then, in the inline view "t", I use having count(tab) != 3 to retain only those rows which are not present into either the three tables ; then I use a logic with the result of sum(tab) to distinguish the source tables.
- Then, in inline view "tt", I use count analytic function to count rows by REGION and by tX_missing
- Then in inline view "ttt", I group the rows by region, and I prepare the output format (per column)
- And finally, I use listagg

```sql
with compare_tab as (
select Region, Customer_ID, 1 tab from t1 union all
select Region, Customer_ID, 2 tab from t2 union all
select Region, Customer_ID, 4 tab from t3
)
select listagg(merge_col, chr(10)) within group (order by merge_col)
from (
  select tt.region
     , '"Table 1", '||tt.region||', '||max(count_t1_missing)
    || ', "Table 2", '||tt.region||', '||max(count_t2_missing)
    || ', "Table 3", '||tt.region||', '||max(count_t3_missing) merge_col
  from ( 
    select region, Customer_ID
    , count(t1_missing)over(partition by REGION, t1_missing) count_t1_missing
    , count(t2_missing)over(partition by REGION, t2_missing) count_t2_missing
    , count(t3_missing)over(partition by REGION, t3_missing) count_t3_missing
    from (
      select Region, Customer_ID--, count(tab) cnt, sum(tab)s
      , case when sum(tab) in (2, 4, 6) then 'Table1' end t1_missing
      , case when sum(tab) in (1, 4, 5) then 'Table2' end t2_missing
      , case when sum(tab) in (1, 2, 3) then 'Table3' end t3_missing
      from compare_tab
      group by Region, Customer_ID
      having count(tab) != 3
      order by 1, 2, 3, 4
    ) t
  )tt
  group by tt.region
)ttt
;
```

Here is my sample data

```sql
create table t1 (Region varchar2(50), Customer_ID number(4));
create table t2 (Region varchar2(50), Customer_ID number(4));
create table t3 (Region varchar2(50), Customer_ID number(4));

insert all
when mod(customer, 3) = 0  then INTO t3 (Region, Customer_ID) values (region, customer)
when mod(customer, 2) = 0  then INTO t2 (Region, Customer_ID) values (region, customer)
when mod(customer, 5) = 0 then INTO t1 (Region, Customer_ID) values (region, customer)
select lpad(case when mod(level, 5) = 0 then 5 else mod(level, 5) end, 3, '0') region, level customer
from dual
connect by level <= 25
order by 1
;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following gets the distribution of values for each region:

```
select region, in_1, in_2, in_3, count(*)
from (select region, customer_id, max(in_1) as in_1, max(in_2) as in_2, max(in_3) as in_3
      from ((select region, customer_id, 1 as in_1, 0 as in_2, 0 as in_3
             from table1
            ) union all
            (select region, customer_id, 0 as in_1, 1 as in_2, 0 as in_3
             from table2
            ) union all
            (select region, customer_id, 0 as in_1, 0 as in_2, 1 as in_3
             from table3
            ) 
           ) t
      group by region, customer_id
     ) rc
group by region, in_1, in_2, in_3
order by region, count(*) desc;
```

It is not 100% clear to me how to convert this to the format you want.  But I think this would be:

```
select region,
       ( 'Table1: ' || count(*) - sum(in_1) || ';' ||
         'Table2: ' || count(*) - sum(in_2) || ';' ||
         'Table3: ' || count(*) - sum(in_3) 
       ) as summary
from (select region, customer_id, max(in_1) as in_1, max(in_2) as in_2, max(in_3) as in_3
      from ((select region, customer_id, 1 as in_1, 0 as in_2, 0 as in_3
             from table1
            ) union all
            (select region, customer_id, 0 as in_1, 1 as in_2, 0 as in_3
             from table2
            ) union all
            (select region, customer_id, 0 as in_1, 0 as in_2, 1 as in_3
             from table3
            ) 
           ) t
      group by region, customer_id
     ) rc
group by region
order by region;
```

However, I think the first format is more informative.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need such query with `LISTAGG()` function containing `OUTER JOIN`s among tables

```
SELECT LISTAGG( NVL2(t2.Customer_ID,'"Table2"','"Table1"')||','||t3.Region||','
                   ||t3.Customer_ID, ';' )      
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t3.Customer_ID) AS "Result"
  FROM t3
  LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.Customer_ID = t3.Customer_ID
  LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.Customer_ID = t3.Customer_ID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=936be48e348984e00196a4953cd86062)</kbd>